# Adding a new column in a DataTable after calculation with different values from different database table and showing in the gridview in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, gridview, datatable

I have a SQLite database which is used in my C#.NET application. I need to implement a gridview to show a table with three columns. Values of two columns (apple, percent) will come from the following table fruit-

```
Id  apple   number   percent
1   red      101     0.60
2   green    102     0.80
3   blue     103     0.20
4   white    104     0.40
5   Mesanda  105     0.50
```

Values of the third column come from a function. The function will take a value from the percent column and increase it by 1% calculate with other values taken from other tables.  I used following code to extract data from two columns and show in the gridview.

```
  public DataTable impactOfIncrease()
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
            command.CommandText = "SELECT apple, percent FROM fruit";          

            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable Impact = new DataTable();

            DataColumn appleName = Impact.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            DataColumn percentage = Impact.Columns.Add("percentage  (%)", typeof(double));
            DataColumn AfterIncrease = Impact.Columns.Add("After 1% Increase", typeof(double));

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Impact.Rows.Add(new object[] { reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString(), GetPercentIncreasedByOne() });
            }

            reader.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();

            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
            bSource.DataSource = Impact;
            return Impact;

        }

public double GetPercentIncreasedByOne()
            {
                double result = 0.0;
                DataTable pdt = GetTable();
                foreach (DataRow dr in pdt.Rows)
                {
                    result += ValuesIncreasedByOne(dr["id"].ToString());
                }            
                return result;

            }
```

Calling the method

GridView.DataSource = classApple.impactOfIncrease();

I got the following data in gridview-

```
 Name     percentage(%)   After 1% Increase
 red      0.60              45.456
 green    0.80              45.456
 blue     0.20              45.456
 white    0.40              45.456
 Mesanda  0.50              45.456
```

The values of third column (After 1% Increase) come from GetPercentIncreasedByOne(). It is showing same values in the third column which is not consistent. I need to take paercent of each row and calculate corresponding value for the third column. Could anyone help me how to do that ? Is there anything wrong with implmentation approach ?

Answer (score 1):

When you read data from table to show two columns you should call this function, pass parameter and get third value.

Comment: inside the while loop ? but, first i have to increase the value of percent by 1.

Comment: Yes. If you can't do that you can write two loop.

Comment: like this Impact.Rows.Add(new object[] { reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString(), reader[2].GetPercentIncreasedByOne() }); ?

Comment: caould you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: i have added the function like Impact.Rows.Add(new object[] { reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString(), GetPercentIncreasedByOne() }); but the values of the third column are not consistent. It is showing same values in every row.

Comment: I am getting same value in the third row. you said about writing two loops. can you please give me any clue how to solve it ?